# Accuracy of covariance estimated with method of moments

Tags: statistics, covariance, parameter-estimation

I want to estimate the Covariance Matrix for a multidimensional gaussian distribution. My research so far has led me to the conclusion that the method of moments is the most appropriate solution for my case.

I already found that it is unbiased $E[\sigma_{\text{estimated}}] = \sigma_{\text{actual}}$. Now I need to know how many samples I need for a "good enough" accuracy. So I need some relationship between the number of samples and the variance of the estimate of the covariance matrix (so like $E[Var^2]-E[Var]^2$) or some other measure for the accuracy of the estimated variance.

Any ideas or links?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos!

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "the" variance?  Because there are multiple variances and covariances, not all will be estimated with the same precision for a given sample size.

Comment: @JimB I am sorry I meant the Covariance matrix (I edited the question). The calculation of the sample Covariance Matrix can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Sample_covariance)